# Git diverge from upstream but continue contributing to upstream

Tags: git

When I fork a project, I usually do it to make my own changes to it and keep it to myself. But for some projects I'd also like to contribute to the original project. However, sometimes the changes I make may not be compatible with the requirements and goals of the upstream project. How should i go about working with git so that i can simultaneously achieve both these goals? The only way I can think of is to work on a separate branch - keeping the master in sync with the upstream master, while keeping another "my_master" branch for my changes. I don't know if there are better ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is exactly the correct workflow.  Keep your changes separate from the upstream branch.  This way you can always update your local copy of the upstream branch without a problem, *and* you can merge these upstream changes into your development branch (or rebase your branch on top of the updates).

If you want to contribute a change upstream, you would create a third branch from the upstream branch, and merge in your changes, then submit a patch/make a pull request/etc.

Comment: Exactly - that's the way to do it. The only thing to consider is the naming: Are you going to keep `master` in sync with the `upstream/master`, or are you going to use `master` for your own changes? I do the latter, and have a  separate `upstream_master` that's tracking `upstream/master`.